# Git - Mystery commit removing code

Tags: git

I'm trying to track down why changes from a commit disappeared.   I'm on a branch and some ~70 commits ago in the history is:

```
commit 7000210f4f7abd3f77524cdf1db548d775082e32
Author: John Doe <John.Doe@xyz.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 31 14:53:44 2017 -0400

    CQP3-790 - adding logging for error.

commit 73c4e3c1e65250a6acfb532f7bcadff2f3655a79
Author: Jane Doe <Jane.Doe@xyz.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 31 14:23:43 2017 +0530

    CQP3-415 updated build.xml
```

Looking at the 2nd commit:

```
$ git show 73c4e3c1e65250a6acfb532f7bcadff2f3655a79
commit 73c4e3c1e65250a6acfb532f7bcadff2f3655a79
Author: Jane Doe <Jane.Doe@xyz.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 31 14:23:43 2017 +0530

    CQP3-415 updated build.xml

diff --git a/build.xml b/build.xml
index c898f15..9ddc1b8 100644
--- a/build.xml
+++ b/build.xml
@@ -102,8 +102,8 @@
                                <include name="*.properties"/>
                        </fileset>
                </copy>
-               <copy todir="${build.dir}/conf/neptune">
-                       <fileset dir="${src.dir}/conf/neptune">
+               <copy todir="${build.dir}/jar/conf/neptune">
+                       <fileset             
    dir="${basedir}/lib/cqp_batch/src/conf/neptune">
                                <include name="*.xml" />
                                <include name="*.properties" />
                        </fileset>
```

And when I diff the two commits, I see the removed code:

```
$ git diff 73c4e3c1e65250a6acfb532f7bcadff2f3655a79     \
        7000210f4f7abd3f77524cdf1db548d775082e32 build.xml
diff --git a/build.xml b/build.xml
index 9ddc1b8..f9c4a87 100644
--- a/build.xml
+++ b/build.xml
@@ -102,12 +102,6 @@
                                <include name="*.properties"/>
                        </fileset>
                </copy>
-               <copy todir="${build.dir}/jar/conf/neptune">
-                       <fileset     \
        dir="${basedir}/lib/cqp_batch/src/conf/neptune">
-                               <include name="*.xml" />
-                               <include name="*.properties" />
-                       </fileset>
-               </copy>
                <!-- Added for EmailEngine -->
                <copy todir="${build.dir}/jar/conf/emailengine">
                        <fileset         \
    dir="${basedir}/lib/cqp_batch/src/conf/emailengine">
@@ -230,4 +224,4 @@
                <echo message="Package url is         \
    ${pkg.repo}/batch/tags/${DSTAMP}_${TSTAMP}_src_${source.rev}" />-->
    </target>
 </project>
-
+
\ No newline at end of file
```

But, the kicker is that the commit that followed had nothing to do with the build.xml file:

```
$ git show 7000210f4f7abd3f77524cdf1db548d775082e32
commit 7000210f4f7abd3f77524cdf1db548d775082e32
Author: John Doe <John.Doe@xyz.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 31 14:53:44 2017 -0400

    CQP3-790 - adding logging for error.

diff --git a//SomeImpl.java b/SomeImpl.java
index 04a4a94..aa399d5 100644
--- 
<snip>
```

As a side mystery, when I do a:

```
$ git log --full-history -5 build.xml
```

It fingers a different commit that also has nothing to do with the build.xml.

It seems like the repository has the change, but lost track of the commit responsible.

Ideas?

Comment: Pay attention to merges. Changes can be lost/introduced in a merge commit which are easy to miss.

Comment: Are you sure `73c4e3c1e6` is really a parent of `7000210f4f`? Use `git show --pretty=raw ...` to see it

Comment: If there are several merged branches they can be just coincided commits on parallel branches.

Comment: $ git show --pretty=raw 7000210f4f7abd3f77524cdf1db548d775082e32
commit 7000210f4f7abd3f77524cdf1db548d775082e32
tree 415a32c7c9d9497e823e7a0ace06d811fbbf42f2
parent f41ee0923d84744a0d75ab744c443c0285f389df

Comment: The parent above is one that fingered in the 'git log --full-history -5 build.xml ' command and it has nothing to do with build.xml.     My only thought is that every book that I read says that deleting commits that have been shared is evil and source of confusion.   I wonder if this is it?